# How do I get the last directory path of the string in one variable and rest will be store in other variable

Tags: batch-file

I want to split the string into two parts using batch script
For example  "aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd\eeee"
str1= aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd
str2= eeee

Can any one please suggest me how to split the strings into two parts?

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "mydir=aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd\eeee"
FOR %%a IN ("c:\%mydir%") DO (SET "str1=%%~pa"&SET "str2=%%~nxa")
if "%mydir:~0,1" neq "\" SET "str1=%str1:~1,-1%"
SET str

GOTO :EOF
```

Simple enough - or have you got a drivename or leading `\` that you haven't told us about?

Edited to compensate for optional leading <kbd>\</kbd>

Comment: This will convert a relative path into an absolute path, meaning the path to the current directory will be prepended to str1. Also, the simple FOR will attempt to expand wildcards - better to use FOR /F. Also, why enable delayed expansion when you don't use it? The delayed expansion will lead to corrupted results if the original path contains `!`.

Comment: @dbenham: Relative path will be preserved.

Comment: My bad. You are right. I didn't read your code carefully enough. However, your code has the opposite problem. A value of `\a\b\c\d\e` incorrectly yields `a\b\c\d` for str1 when it should yield `\a\b\c\d` The only time the root \ is preserved is if the original string includes the drive. I think a correct solution should differentiate between `abc` and `\abc`

Comment: @dbenham: certainly. Sometimes you ave to choose between a solution to fit the specification and one that takes into consideration logical or anticipated variations. On the one hand, you have to weather the follow-up "but what if"s. On the other, you get no response or "that's too complicated." Not going to win either way, but that's life.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "string=aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd\eeee"

set "str1="
set "str2="
rem Separate the string in quote-delimited parts at "\" chars and process each part:
for %%a in ("%string:\=" "%") do (
   set "str1=!str1!\!str2!"
   set "str2=%%~a"
)

echo str1 = "%str1:~2%"
echo str2 = "%str2%"
```

A compact form:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "string=aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd\eeee"

set "str1="
rem The same, in compact form:
set "str2=%string:\=" & set "str1=!str1!\!str2!" & set "str2=%"

echo str1 = "%str1:~1%"
echo str2 = "%str2%"
```

These methods fail if the string contain wild-card `* ?` characters.

Comment: The current code has an additional limitation that values containing `!` will be corrupted. I don't see anything "standard" about this solution. But it certainly is effective, provided you don't run against any of the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the string represents a path of some kind. I assume you want to preserve any relative nature of the path, and you also want to preserve any wild card characters.

The following should be robust, provided the path is valid. In an effort to preserve relative paths, I intentionally prefix the original string with an invalid path of `\|` that can easily be removed.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "str=%~1"

for /f "delims=" %%A in ("\|%str%") do if "%%~pA" neq "\" (
  for /f "delims=| tokens=1*" %%B in ("%%~pA") do set "str1=%%C"
  set "str2=%%~nxA"
) else (
  set "str1="
  for /f "delims=| tokens=*" %%B in ("%%~nxA") do set "str2=%%B"
)
if not defined str1 goto :done
if "%str1:~1%" neq "" set "str1=%str1:~0,-1%"
:done

:: Display the results
set str
```

The only potential issues I'm aware of are if the original path is not valid:

- `/` characters are converted to `\`
- consecutive `\` are converted to a single `\`
- Any leading `|` are stripped from the "path"

Comment: Thanks every one for your responses.